# Magento 2 Setup Custom Module Download Using Composer

Tags: magento2, module, composer

**GitHub Link** -> https://github.com/mahesh-code-work/Module-Learn/

I create one small basic module and try to install using composer.

How to set up the whole setting and what is the right way to do this?

Please explain the steps to achieve?

**Update**

*Added Module to packagist.org*

https://packagist.org/packages/customdol/productlist

[image]

Comment: try to run ``composer require customdol/productlist 1.0.0``

Comment: @GohilRajesh not working Please help me to solve above issue.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are the author of the package you should create a release if you think that your version may be used in production. also try ``composer  require customdol/productlist:dev-master``

Comment: @GohilRajesh you can check the release https://github.com/mahesh-code-work/Module-Learn/ Could not find package customdol/productlist.  
                                                 
  Did you mean this?                             
      customdol/productlist  error come

Comment: I think when you first create a repo and connect to Packagist, you need to create a "release" in Github. If not, it defaults to "dev-master" which if the repo/project you are trying to add to has "stable" as the minimum stability, it causes problems here. But if you go into Github for your new repo and navigate to "Release" and create a new release, even one tagged "0.0.1" then Packagist (Composer) will accept that as a satisfactory minimum-stability match.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149552/composer-packagist-could-not-find-package-for-minimum-stability

Comment: @GohilRajesh I have added 0.0.1 and updated the composer.json file but still the same error into local, but when I install the same module on any test server then it works. So please tell me why it's not working on my local PC. I check my both composer.json file are the same at the local and test server. Both are fresh Magento 2.4.3p1 without any third-party module and theme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133401/discussion-between-msquare-and-gohil-rajesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://packagist.org/ to allow your module to install by composer.
It is pretty easy you can read more using this link https://packagist.org/about

If it will help us then you can up vote and accept this as useful.

Comment: Could not find a version of package customdol/productlist matching your minimum-stability (dev). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired  
   stability. Error Comes when run composer require customdol/productlist. Please check my composer.json file. and please explain in steps.